# Doing calculations of decimal to binary and using one's complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

what is 18 base - 13 base 10 using one's complement?
i do not know how to work it and how the one's complement works.
I know that 18 is equal to 10010(2) and 13 is 1101 (2) but I am not sure if I should subtract and then do the one's complement or do it before subtracting. so please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is positive, you don't have to worry about one's complement.  Just subtract in base $10$ and convert to base $2$ or subtract the base $2$ values you have.